# Wireguard VPN Raspberry Pi CLIENT

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, vpn, wireguard

Does any one have any experience in connecting to a Wireguard VPN from a Raspberry pi?

The VPN is set up correctly and I can connect to it using my phone and laptop but I can't get any info on connecting from a pi (Pi must be the client).

I've spent hours on google and there's thousands of post showing how to set up a VPN with a pi as the host. But NOTHING on connecting from a pi.

Does anyone have any idea how to get Wireguard client on a pi? Or how to connect to a Wireguard VPN from a pi?

I am running the latest Raspbian Buster with desktop OS. I am using Pi 3B+.

Comment: Although you do not mention an operating system, it seems to me the real question is *"How do I configure a wireguard client **on linux**?"* -- unless of course you are using Android Things or Windows IoT, RISC, etc (which you should indicate if you want appropriate help).

Comment: If you also failed to mention the OS in your hours on google then that might be a problem too; the first thing I found searching *'wireguard client linux'* turned up this: https://www.wireguard.com/install/ which explicitly refers to Debian (from which Raspbian is derived) and you should start there and [the conceptual overview](https://www.wireguard.com/#conceptual-overview), which introduces client configuration.

Comment: wireguard on pi 2 (v 1.2+), 3, 3+, 4 is straight forward - on pi A, pi B and pi 2 (v 1.1 or earlier) and pi zero W is covered by [this guide](https://github.com/adrianmihalko/raspberrypiwireguard/wiki/Install-WireGuard-on-Raspberry-Pi-1,-2-(not-v1.2),-Zero,-Zero-W)

Answer (score 3):

> ... but I can't get any info on connecting from a pi

For this reason some times ago I have made a proof of concept but not completely finished it yet. There you will also find how to setup a Raspberry Pi as Wireguard client. This may give you some ideas what to do with your project. Have a look at [How to bridge an access point with a remote network by Wireguard? (with the use of systemd-networkd)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106337/79866).