# Create a wifi accesspoint (sharing wifi) with traffic routed over VPN

Tags: networking, wifi

I know we can create a wifi hotspot, sharing ethernet over wifi but is there a way I can create a new wifi hotspot while staying connected to a wifi. So something like sharing wifi.

My use case is I am using a VPN, which creates a new interface ppp0. I want to create a new wifi access point whose traffic will be sent over the VPN(on the ppp0 interface).

Trying to setup something like:

(Internet) --- (home router wifi) --- (raspberry pi connected over wifi) --- (wifi accesspoint on raspberry pi, routing traffic over VPN) --- (my other gadgets)

Comment: You need to add more details. Did you manage to create ppp0 and the access point? If no, what was the issue? If yes, then what subsequent step caused a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a WiFi router/repeater with a WiFi uplink to your internet router. How to do it you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).

If you have this running then based on this you should be able to create an additional VPN tunnel, either with using a [Simple **openVPN** with static keys](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98186/79866), or using [Wireguard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106337/79866), or install **PiVPN**. I do not know if it is possible to integrate PiVPN into the WiFi repeater setup. Maybe there are preconditions set by PiVPN which do not fit.

I would prefer **Wireguard** because it is simple to use and very well integrated into **systemd-networkd**, that is in general used for the WiFi repeater setup.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I tried to follow the instructions at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge/89804#89804 in "Setup wifi repeater" till the beginning of "Setup bridge", but that didn't create any hotspot for me. I didn't see any error while running these commands. Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot. Also one thing to note here is that before starting with the instructions, I already had ppp0 interface running. This is the VPN that tunnels all my data.

Comment: @Alan I have the setup started with a fresh flash Raspberry Pi OS and tested. I cannot say much if you don't start with it and already have a configured network. But I have done some other setups starting with the described installation and then extended it with additional networking like a VPN. That's what I suggested in my answer. Do you have a spare SD Card to try that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will give it a try tonight.